# What does "ac" or "acc" mean in an address?

Tags: significado, españa, abreviaturas

Quite similar to *[What does "bis" mean in an address?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28260/12637)*, I have sometimes seen "ac" or "acc" in a number over a door in the street in Spain. This is taken from Google Maps from a street in Seville:

[image: 28 AC.]

I don't know if this is a general rule for all Spain, or some cities only, or it may be something outdated as I can't find any modern-looking numbers with that abbreviation, modern-looking numbers just say 42 and 42A.

What does "ac" or "acc" mean in this context?

Comment: Is this question about Spanish? ;-)

Comment: @DGaleano I understand that "ac" is an abbreviation of a Spanish word, and I want to know what word is that. Of course you can decide this question has nothing to do with the Spanish language and vote to close it. You know that I'm always trying to push the limits of the site and sometimes I may wander off... :-)

Comment: I was thinking that it could be "avenida calle," but that seems to be a Colombian thing from what I can tell. Could it perhaps be acceso? That is, "acceso al 28" or something like that? I found an address that used "ac. e," which I was thinking could be "acceso exterior."

Comment: I've seen that there are streets called "Avenida Calle Carretera" (ACC). It might be a comprehensive way of embracing all kinds of roads with a single abbreviation.

Comment: Good question. [Here](https://www.salafabiola.com/la-sala/) is an example of a place in Seville whose address includes "Acc".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Accesorios**

> Tendrán la condición de accesorios (acc) los números asignados a
>   aquellos locales cuyo acceso se realice por una vía distinta a aquella
>   en la que está situado el acceso principal del edificio,

según esta página web del [ayuntamiento de Granada](https://www.granada.org/intranet/bolcalles.nsf/wenviados/E26A48CFE073D77CC1257FA20036A74E?opendocument).

Confieso que nunca me había topado con esta abreviatura.

Comment: Muy buen hallazgo. Ahora sí tiene sentido el cartel.